# SP2-0734:Unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..."

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am not sure, why below is throwing an error during the RLM deployment. However, same query is successfully executing in Oracle SQL developer.

I do not see any space in the query, and just to be in safer side I put "SET SQLBLANKLINES ON" if in case sql*plus client is being used but no luck. Here is my script

```
create table PROFILE (
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
EXT_ID varchar2(150) NOT NULL,
ENV varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
INTERNAL_PROFILE_ID varchar2(150) NOT NULL,
STATUS_ID INT NOT NULL,
NUMBER_OF_DAYS INT NOT NULL,
TAGS varchar2(150),
APPLIED_DATE TIMESTAMP,
CREATED TIMESTAMP,
UPDATED TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT PROFILE_INFO_VULN_ID_OPERATING_ENV_UNQ  UNIQUE (EXT_ID,ENV)
);

commit;
```

The error shows as

INFO: /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/rpm/bin/sqlplus -L -s USER:xyz @/rlmstage/bmc/rlm/rlm_8012912_106159671_1709878573/content/script.sql

**01:16:33|INFO> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..." - rest of line ignored.
01:16:33|INFO> SP2-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.**

Comment: No way that it works anywhere. There are no VULN_ID nor OPERATING_ENV columns in that table, so you can't create unique constraint on non-existent columns. Besides, depending on database version you use, constraint name *might* be too long (older versions - up to 11g - support identifiers whose names are max 30 characters long). Therefore, consider posting what you really have and specify database version.

Comment: Now that you fixed column names, I ran that piece of code and it executes OK in my SQLPlus, which means that there must be something else that causes your problems. Instead of posting only a script, could you copy/paste **your** SQLPlus session so that we'd see what you did and how Oracle responded?

Comment: I am deploying my script via RLM deployment tool where it throws this error .However, manual execution in sql developer is running fine.below is the local param which is being used

ORACLEDB_HOME => /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/rpm

Comment: even after reducing the constraint name below 30 chars, there is no luck. Below is the log

02:16:59|INFO> INFO: /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/rpm/bin/sqlplus -L -s USER:XYZ @/rlmstage/bmc/rlm/rlm_8012912_106159671_1709882199/content/Script.sql

02:16:59|INFO> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..." - rest of line ignored.
02:16:59|INFO> SP2-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.
**script.sql is my script.

Comment: Have you run that actual script manually, or rewritten the same statement in another client? As you haven't shown anything in the log that relates to the actual `create` part maybe there are some invisible characters at the end of the line before `constraint`, or something else that has been lost rewriting it here, that means SQL\*Plus ignores that part?

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no VULN_ID column in your table definition
2. PROFILE_INFO_VULN_ID_OPERATING_ENV_UNQ is 38 chars and that may be not supported on older ORACLE versions

Comment: sorry..it was   a typo. have corrected the question.

Comment: And under 21c it works so it's really related to your DB version and the length of the identifier.

Comment: no luck even after bringing the constraint name below 30 chars
Actually its running successfully in oracle sql developer(21c is same what i am using) . However same script if i am trying using RLM deployment tool , its failing at the CONSTRAINT keyword.

in the log i see below
`
02:16:59|INFO> INFO: /opt/oraClient/11.2.0.4/rpm/bin/sqlplus -L -s USER:XYZ @/rlmstage/bmc/rlm/rlm_8012912_106159671_1709882199/content/Script.sql

02:16:59|INFO> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONSTRAINT..." - rest of line ignored.
02:16:59|INFO> SP2-0042: unknown command ")" - rest of line ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like *RLM deployment tool* doesn't recognize `constraint` the way you put it.

If you can edit `script.sql` (I believe you can), then omit that clause entirely from `create table` and create unique constraint separately with `alter table`. Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE profile
  2  (
  3     id                    INT PRIMARY KEY,
  4     ext_id                VARCHAR2 (150) NOT NULL,
  5     env                   VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
  6     internal_profile_id   VARCHAR2 (150) NOT NULL,
  7     status_id             INT NOT NULL,
  8     number_of_days        INT NOT NULL,
  9     tags                  VARCHAR2 (150),
 10     applied_date          TIMESTAMP,
 11     created               TIMESTAMP,
 12     updated               TIMESTAMP
 13  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE profile
  2     ADD CONSTRAINT profile_unq UNIQUE (ext_id, env);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

By the way, these are **DDL** statements which implicitly commit changes to data dictionary. You don't have to `commit` manually.